# Play framework 2.8.8 (JAVA) trying to connect with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, playframework

Im new on Play framework and i've started a project with it specially the version 2.8.8. I'm using mongoDB for my project and eclipse for play. now  now i'm trying to connect my database with play. I read a lot of things about Ebean which is play ORM for database connection i've try it  but i still not handle my problem. my goal is to connect to my database made a request that will register information in the collection(mongo)
can somebody show me what to do how it works? I  need some useful tips  configuration or sample model to view  so that i can moving forward on my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include these dependencies in your build.sbt for interacting with mongo. (you can use your relevant versions. the below-given versions are being used with play 2.7)

> "org.jongo" % "jongo" % "1.3.1", "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" %
> "3.10.2"

Mongo Repository(Connector/Dao) class example :-

```
import handlers.MongoConnectionHandler;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.WriteResult;
import models.mongo.Message;
import org.jongo.MongoCollection;
import org.jongo.MongoCursor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import skeletons.requests.ChatHistoryRequest;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Singleton
public class MessageMongoRepository {

    private final MongoCollection messageCollection;
    
    @Inject
    public MessageMongoRepository(MongoConnectionHandler mongoConnectionHandler) {
        messageCollection = mongoConnectionHandler.getCollection("messages");
    }

    public List<Message> fetchRecords() {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("f1", "val 1");
        query.put("f2", "val2");
        query.put("f3","val 3" );
        BasicDBObject sort = new BasicDBObject();
        MongoCursor<Message> messages = null;
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            messages = messageCollection.find(query.toString()).sort(sort.toString()).limit(request.getSize()).as(Message.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in fetching messages");
            throw e;
        }
        if (messages != null) {
            while (messages.hasNext()) {
                messageList.add(messages.next());
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("No messages");
        }

        return messageList;
    }

    public String saveRecord(Message rec) {
        WriteResult result;
        try {
            result = messageCollection.save(rec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return result.getUpsertedId().toString();
    }
}
```

The message is a User Defined Java Class

MongoConnectionHandler Example

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import org.jongo.Jongo;
import org.jongo.MongoCollection;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MongoConnectionHandler {

    private final Config config;

    private final DB db;
    private final Jongo jongo;
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;
    private static final MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1000)
            .maxConnectionIdleTime(1000)
            .socketTimeout(1000)
            .maxWaitTime(1000)
            .build();

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Inject
    public MongoConnectionHandler(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
        String user = this.config.getString("mongo.auth.user");
        String pass = this.config.getString("mongo.auth.pass");
        String authDb = this.config.getString("mongo.auth.db");
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, authDb, pass.toCharArray());
        List<ServerAddress> serverAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] hostList = this.config.getString("mongo.host").split(",");
        for (String host : hostList) {
            String[] ipPortPair = host.split(":");
            ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(ipPortPair[0], Integer.valueOf(ipPortPair[1]));
            serverAddressList.add(serverAddress);
        }
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddressList, mongoCredential, mongoClientOptions);
        db = mongoClient.getDB(this.config.getString("mongo.db"));
        jongo = new Jongo(db);
    }

    public MongoCollection getCollection(String name) {
        MongoCollection collection = null;
        try {
            collection = jongo.getCollection(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while getting collection : {}", name);
            throw e;
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact i'm using play framework JAVA 2.8.8 . so i tried to add my dependency in build.sbt  like this : libraryDependencies +=  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.12.7" . so when i use your code it still don't work for me . i didn't master well what to do i think so help me further

Comment: Add your build.sbt & code snippets as well. That'll provide more perspective into the problem.

Comment: I  want to connect play to mongoDb by  using mongo driver legacy . so i added this : 
libraryDependencies +=  "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-legacy" % "4.2.3" to my build.sbt . and this :   #mongodb.default.host=localhost
mongodb.default.port=27017
mongodb.default.db=JBJ
mongodb.collections=["administrateur","article","client","commande","facture"]  to my app.conf .  now help me to create a connection class so that i can use my databse created on mongo and made requets

Answer (score 0):

heres how you get mongodb and play framework to co-operate
the understanding of modules in play will be necessary
check out this module follow the steps and you get mongodb working with play
https://github.com/morellik/play-morphia

(please mark correct if this answer helps,i was stuck here recently)